# How can I use expression inside formatted string in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The `if` expression is not working if used inside of `fmt` string.

Why, and how to make it work?

```
import strformat

let v = if true: 1 else: 2 # <= Works
echo fmt"{v}"

echo fmt"{if true: 1 else: 2}" # <= Error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works:

```
import std/strformat
let x = 3.14
assert fmt"{(if x!=0: 1.0/x else: 0):.5}" == "0.31847"
assert fmt"{(if true: 1 else: 2)}" == "1"
assert fmt"{if true\: 1 else\: 2}" == "1"
```

and avoids conflicts with format specifier. See https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/17700 for more details.

Answer (score 8):

## why?

because `fmt` uses `:` to separate value of expression from format specifier so (see [docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strformat.html#implementation-details) and [implementation](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-2/lib/pure/strformat.nim#L554)) the line

`echo fmt"{if true: 1 else: 2}"`

is expanded by the macro into

```
var temp = newStringOfCap(educatedCapGuess)
temp.formatValue if true, " 1 else: 2"
temp
```

which clearly does not compile.

## how?

### update

currently (April 2021) in devel branch there is a enhancement that allows to use any expression inside a formatted string. For the specific case mentioned you need to surround the expression by parenthesis:

```
echo fmt"{(if true: 1 else: 2)}"
```

the new enhancements also allow to use curly brackets in expression (escaping them).

See:

- RFC: https://github.com/nim-lang/RFCs/issues/366
- a [first](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/17694) and a [second](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/17700) PR that added the implementation
- recent forum discussion: https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/7052

This enhancement will be released for the general public in the next stable version (likely to be 1.6).

### old content

I guess it could be seen as a limitation of `fmt` and I do not think there is currently a way to use an expression with `:` in `fmt` where it does not act as a format specificier.

One way to fix this would be to provide an additional `formatSpecifierSeparator` keyword argument in order to change the default `:` and be able to do something like:

`echo "{if true: 1 else: 2}".fmt('|')`

Another way would be to change the implementation of `strformatImpl` and make sure that the part before a `:` actually compiles before interpreting `:` as a formatSpecifier separator.

Both of these ways imply a PR in nim-lang code and would be available after next release or on devel, if accepted and merged.

Comment: I upvoted your comment but, ¿do Nim really want this? Python had a moment with multiple string interpolation methods plus Templates, and it was one of the weirdest part of the language. And you cannot include complex code in a f-string or you get a SyntaxError. Nim has the strutils %, the strformat, the SCFilters, and a template/macro system that allows basically to do whatever you need. Do it need full compiler inside fmt""?

Comment: You raise very good points. I also agree with you that Python situation in that respect is not that nice (I did use https://pyformat.info/ a lot!). I agree that Nim does not *need* to support this type of syntax but it might *want* at some point. I find the example simple enough to be reasonable given what fmt can be expected to do. I do feel that a complete answer to the question should include some suggestion on how to make it work, if one actually really cares. And if somebody will care enough to open a PR in Nim we will probably also find out if Nim wants that! :)

Comment: @xbello I never had slightest issue with having full support for string interpolation in TypeScript, Kotlin or Ruby.

Comment: @xbello you may say that it would be complicated to implement in Nim and it's better to keep it simple - and that is ok and a valid argument. But saying that string interpolation in general has some inherent problems is not a valid objection.

Comment: came up again today in nim chat and there was discussion of possible workarounds (implement a ternay operator without : or use elvis) and of alternative implementation changes (using parenthesis to protect from parsing formatSpecifier): https://irclogs.nim-lang.org/04-02-2021.html#09:00:28